# In Netlogo, how to randomly choose an element from a list, and let this element plus one, and then create a new list?

Tags: list, random, netlogo

For example, now I have a list: [0 0 0]

I want to randomly choose an element from this list, for example, randomly I choose the first element.

Then I plus it by 1.

So now the new list is [1 0 0].

My question is how to create this new list [1 0 0] in Netlogo?

Comment: I mean I want to know the whole programming process of it, i.e., from the random choice to the creation of the new list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For these basic matters, checking the [NetLogo Programming Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html) should help you. If you're stuck, you can show what you tried and get help here.  PS: edit your question instead of extending it with comments.

Answer (score 2):

To get a random item from a list, you'd normally want to use [the `one-of` primitive](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of).  However, you want to replace the item you get, which means you need to know the index of the random item from the list, too.

So what we'll do is generate a random index using the length of the list, then we'll use that to get the item from the list at that index, using [the `item` primitive](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#item).  Then we'll update it and put it back using [the `replace-item` primitive](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#replace-item) that will give us our new list.

```
to test
  let my-list [0 0 0]
  let random-index (random (length my-list))
  show random-index
  let value (item random-index my-list)
  let new-value (value + 1)
  let new-list (replace-item random-index my-list new-value)
  show new-list
end
```

For more basic info on lists, see [the Lists section of the programming guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#lists).

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try your code tomorrow to see whether it works!